# Debug AngularJS in Visual Studio (not in VS Code)

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to debug AngularJS code in Visual Studio?
**Note:** I'm not talking about VS Code.
I would like to be able to set breakpoints and see what's happening there.
I'm aware of other IDE-s which allow us to do that.
So is it possible to use Visual Studio IDE for that?

Comment: why cant you use chrome wed developer tool

Comment: of course it's possible;  what happens when you try?  what are you asking for help with, exactly?

Comment: When I run the app, Visual Studio disables the breakpoint by telling that that part is not loaded. (I was using firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays we can use Edge as well instead of IE. That is a better solution since it's chromium based and has less issues compared to IE.

Answer (score 3):

put break point in visual studio(Angularjs code) and run your application in IE so that break point will hit into visual studio

Comment: So it turned out I had to use IE instead of Firefox. Thanks.

Comment: most certainly related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Comment: In 2021 this works with Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft Edge.